# BufferKnife Creating Problems while building gradle Android Studio

Tags: android

I think Butterknife is creating problem while building the gradle of my project.
It is messing with multidexArchiveBuilderException.also I'm getting app: transformClasseswithDexBuilderForDebug Error

Error:

```
    Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\Suyash Ekhande\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\butterknife-runtime-10.1.0.aar\be763a4d7356121de0276e3f3b6e563a\jars\classes.jar
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing butterknife/Unbinder.class
Error:com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\Suyash Ekhande\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\butterknife-runtime-10.1.0.aar\be763a4d7356121de0276e3f3b6e563a\jars\classes.jar
```

Gradle: app

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.esuraksha.suraksharesponder"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1') {
        exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
    }
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Butterknife version [9.0.0](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-900-2019-01-03) and above requires Java 8 which needs to be enabled explicitly.

```
android {
  ...
  // Configure for each module that uses butterknife.
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```